# Show that $Y\sim\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

let $X\sim N(0,1)$ be a standard normally distributed stochastic variable and let $Y=X^2$.

Show that $Y\sim\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, ie. $Y\sim\chi^2(1)$.

Comment: What are you allowed to know, and what do you need to show?  For example I would take the distribution of $Y$ to be the definition of $\chi^2(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mgf:

$$E[e^{tY}] = E[e^{tX^2}] = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{tx^2} f_X(x) dx$$

[$$ = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{(t-1/2)(x^2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Integral_of_a_Gaussian_function)

Hence $Y \sim \chi^2(1)$

Comment: What does $E$ denote here and why do you use the notation $E[e^{tY}]$?

Comment: @jukka.aalto Seriously? That's expectation. If you don't know expectation or mgf yet, I think you should follow the other answer. This is what Henry was asking on your question

Answer (score 2):

Outline/Hint:
Notice that the range of $X$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$. That makes $Y = X^2$ a many-to-one relationship. Thus, use
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(-\sqrt y)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|}+\frac{f_X(\sqrt y)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|}$$

---

Then,
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt y)^2\right\}}{|-2\sqrt y|}+\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt y)^2\right\}}{|2\sqrt y|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2},$$
which is the density of $\chi^2(1)$.

Comment: Where do you get this result from?

Comment: Well, that's how I learned to do this kind of problem. It's a change of variable. Lots of other people do integrations. That is also possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to do it with integration, but I want to learn this way too.