# Show that $Z^2 \sim Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ using change of variables method

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I found a couple of solutions that use integration but I would like to solve this using random variable transformations. I found [a similar solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1558046) but was hoping to get some more clarity.

Here is how I solved it:

> Let $Y=Z^2$, then $dy=2zdz$.
>
> \begin{align}
> f_Y(y)
> &= f_Z(z) \left| \frac{dz}{dy} \right| \\
> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\frac{1}{2z} \\
> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} \\
> &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y}(\frac{1}{2}y)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{y} \\
> &= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(a)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y}(\frac{1}{2}y)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{y} \\
> \end{align}

We see that the answer has an extra $\frac{1}{2}$ in front. Now, I have a hunch that the reason is because of the absolute value since $Z \sim N(0,1)$, it can be positive and negative. However, I am not really sure how to represent this mathematically and would like to have a better explanation for "why" this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the transformation formula you used *only works* for bijective mappings, and here $Z$ does *not* map bijectively onto $Z^2$; the support of $Z$ is *folded* onto the support of $Z^2$ (there are two real square roots).   Thus we have to account for the contribution from both semi-infinite intervals (the positive and negative rays).

$$\begin{align}f_{Z^2}(y) =&~ f_Z(+\surd y)~\lvert (+\surd y)'\rvert + f_Z(-\surd y)~\lvert (-\surd y)'\rvert
\\[1ex] =&~ \dfrac{f_Z(\surd y)}{\surd y}
\end{align}$$

So long story short, the fun(tion) shall be doubled!

Comment: Isn't $f:Z -> Z^2$ surjective? Since, every element in the codomain $Z^2$ is the image of some element of $Z$? That is, if we just look at positive values of $Z$ (and ignoring the negative ones), we can cover all the values of $Z^2$?

Comment: You need a bijective map as you are working with the inverse function somehow.

Comment: @JustinLiang Sorry, yes.  You have surjection, you needed bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Z^2=|Z|^2$, you can consider the mapping $X\mapsto X^2$, where $X:=|Z|$. Note that the density of $X:=|Z|$ is double that of the standard normal, but lives only on the non-negative axis:
$$
f_X(x) = {2\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}2},\qquad \text{$x>0$},
$$
so the mapping $X\mapsto X^2$ is one-to-one (bijective), and you can apply the change of variables formula directly.

Comment: Yes, a middle map works too; and especially well on symmetric density distributions like this one.